# How to include a plugin/engine in a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-engines, ruby-on-rails-plugins

This is my first time interaction with a rails plugin and I'm unable  to wrap my head around how this thing works. I'm going to make a rails plugin/engine. I want to include this plugin in my rails application(a different project), how can I do it? I found [this](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#inside-an-engine) which suggests to

> At the root of this brand new engine's directory lives a plugin_name.gemspec file. When you include the engine into an application later on, you will do so with this line in the Rails application's Gemfile:

```
gem 'plugin_name', path: 'engines/plugin_name'
```

My question is that how exactly do I do it? I mean when I create a rails application I do not find any `engines` directory in the folder structure. And also which directories from the plugin project do I have to place in the `engines/` directory? 
I created a plugin by doing

```
rails plugin new plugin_name --mountable
```

and it generated following files/directories:

```
|-app/
|-bin/                
|-config/
|-demo_project.gemspec
|-Gemfile
|-Gemfile.lock
|-lib/
|-MIT-LICENSE
|-Rakefile
|-README.md
|-test
  |-dummy
    |-(contains a rails application)
```

Now once I'm done with this plugin, how do I include this in another rails application? What directories do I need to put in `engines/` in addition to including the plugin in the gemfile?

In addition to this I also want some info about what the following is indicating

> Additionally, the `--mountable` option tells the generator to mount the engine inside the dummy testing application located at `test/dummy` by adding the following to the dummy application's routes file at `test/dummy/config/routes.rb`:

```
mount PluginName::Engine => "/plugin_name"
```

What does the mount point indicate and what will be it's role once the plugin is included in a rails application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails engine is an isolated rails app, that is mounted inside main app. Two main reasons to create an engine are isolation of an application part (with possible intent to split the app into pieces) and code reuse (when you use same engine in several apps)

Technically it is a ruby gem, but often engines start (and live) as an isolated part of a larger app, without being completely extracted into own repository, gem publishing etc.
For example, if you have `admin` part of your app, you can make it an engine:

```rb
# in gemfile:
gem 'admin', path: 'engines/admin'

# routes:
mount Admin::Engine => '/admin'

# engine's routes:
resources :foo # => because of being in an engine this will be /admin/foo
```

directory structure can look like:

```
|-app/
|-bin/
|-...
|-config/
  |-application.rb
  |-routes.rb
|-engines/
  |-admin_engine/
    |-app/
      |-controllers/admin/
          |- foo_controller.rb
    |-config/
      |-routes.rb # <- this is engine's routes
    |-lib/
      |-admin/
        |-engine.rb
    |- admin.gemspec
```

Comment: so the engine acts as a standalone app in our host rails application? What about accessing models/classes from the engine in the host app? e.g if the engine has a module named `MyModule` with a model `Message` in it. Will it be accessible in the host app by doing `MyModule::Message` or it has other complications to take care of?

Comment: @Prime since both apps are loaded into a single ruby process - both can access models and other classes from each other, if they know about them. This is not always a good thing, because in some cases can lead to increased cohesion and defeat initial separation goal. But in other cases is indeed useful.

Comment: alright, makes sense. One more thing I'm wondering about is that `engine.rb` is not generated automatically, instead when a plugin is generated the `lib/plugin_name/` contains `railtie.rb` are they interchangeable or they serve different purposes?